# How can i change direction each time one direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightsEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Renderer[] renderers;
    private float lastChangeTime;
    private int greenIndex = 0;

    public void LightsEffect(List<GameObject> objects, Color instantiateColor, Color colorEffect)
    {
        renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
        }

        // Set green color to the first one
        greenIndex = 0;
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Running the effect
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="changeDirection">Changing the lights movement directions - false = forward, true = backward.</param>
    public void LightsEffectCore(float delay, bool changeDirection)
    {
        // Change color each `delay` seconds
        if (Time.time > lastChangeTime + delay)
        {
            lastChangeTime = Time.time;

            // Set color of the last renderer to red
            // and the color of the current one to green
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.red;
            if (changeDirection == true)
            {
                Array.Reverse(renderers);
                changeDirection = false;
            }
            greenIndex = (greenIndex + 1) % renderers.Length;
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

The part of the direction change:

```
if (changeDirection == true)
                {
                    Array.Reverse(renderers);
                    changeDirection = false;
                }
```

The problem is that now it will be true all the time and next time it will be changed to false i will need to reverse the array again but then since it's false it will reverse the array all the time:

```
if (changeDirection == true)
            {
                Array.Reverse(renderers);
                changeDirection = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Reverse(renderers);
                changeDirection = true;
            }
```

But now when it will be change back to false or if the game start as false it will change right back to true and will reverse the array and so on.

I want that when it's true keep it true and once changing it to false keep it false until changing again.
I got messed the flag states and the reversing.

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep track of the previous state and check when it'd different which would require another variable.

Comment: @juharr I added a new flag variable at the top: private bool directionChanged = false; but how do i use it logic in the direction part ?